# SubSonic with MS SQL 2008?

Tags: subsonic

I have been using subsonic with MS SQL 2005 for about a year now. For those of you who have moved to SQL 2008, is subsonic compatiable with that? Have you had too many issues with SubSonic with SQL 2008? Just trying to get a feel if I should upgrade to SQL 2008 at this time or not.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest to try Subsonic 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

I've not used SQL2008 myself, but I know there is still a bug in SubSonic 2.1 and 2.2 in handling the new date only and time only data types (it sees them as strings).

Comment: I can vouch for this still being a problem.
I have an open issue at http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject

Answer (score 3):

SubSonic works great with Sql Server 2008.  If you are at all worried you can download the source and add a reference to the project so that you can fix any errors that come up.

If you download 2.2(which should have been named 2.1.1 as it is a minor bug fix release) you will notice that the Sql Server 2008 provider inherets from the 2005 provider and I believe that it only overrides one function meaning that there is very little that differs between them though you could always fix anything you need to fix if you ever run into a bug(I haven't run into anything in my development and I use SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 2):

I have used (well, am using) SubSonic with both MSSQL 2008 and 2005 in a current project. Same code base is used on both MSSQL 2005 and MSSQL 2008. I have not run into any issues yet (that is, not any issues only occurring on one of either platforms).

I believe SubSonic does not support any features exclusive to MSSQL 2008, but if you're migrating from 2005 anyways, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Subsonic doesn't support all new data type of MSSQL 2008.
for exaple, i've got a problem with Geography