# SubSonic support for SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: subsonic

Does SubSonic support SQL Server 2008 R2?

Regards
Sundar

Comment: dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002296/subsonic-with-ms-sql-2008

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for SubSonic 3.x, but can tell you that 2.x will support both SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 providing that your database doesn't use any of the new 2008 data types (date, time, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'm using SubSonic 3.0 with ActiveRecord T4 templates right now, and they are awesome.

Comment: @Aristos really? I've not noticed any speed problems and most of the SQL queries it generates are sane, if not better than what I'd write. But anyway, you didn't specify what version of SubSonic, so I'm saying SubSonic 3 works. The other answers say SubSonic 2 works. So you got your answer :P

Comment: Yes you have right +1, it did not specify the version. Now subsonic 3 is the slow. I have s2 on my programs, and I discover the different when I start change it with the s3. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363735/benchmark-linq2sql-subsonic2-subsonic3-any-other-ideas-to-make-them-faster

Comment: @Aristos I stand corrected. I thought you were just assuming, but it's true. Doing a [SingleOrDefault](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/258) is 20x slower. And to overcome issues with it not supporting nested queries(or joins), you must basically do a [complete table fetch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529468/left-join-in-subsonic-3). With these issues in light I'm now looking for an alternative ORM

Comment: Subsonic 2 is very good. With some extra optimization inside the code, I have archive super high speed, and easy development. Subsonic 2 is my tool. Subsonic 3 have the problem that need to compile everything again and again in real time, thats why is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that it does. Also see here: [SubSonic with MS SQL 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002296/subsonic-with-ms-sql-2008)